# Which jquery UI CSS file should I use

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I see that the jquery UI distribution contains 15 css files. The jquery.ui.all.css file contains two @import statements -- one for jquery.ui.base.css and another for jquery.ui.theme.css.

The jquery.ui.base.css itself contains 11 import statements for jquery.ui.core.css and then each of the widgets.

I also see a single (larger than others in the folder) file called jquery-ui.css.

Am I off in thinking that if I want all the CSS for a given theme then linking the single jquery-ui.css works but if I want to customize the pieces that I download then importing jquery.ui.all.css and customizing jquery.ui.base.css is the way to go?

Am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the jquery-ui.css.  If you don't need certain widgets, you can uncheck them when [making your (custom) jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download) and they won't be included.

Comment: if you can not use a custom build and don't need certain widgets then use
 jquery.ui.theme.css, jquery.ui.core.css and the widgets sepcific css files (but keep in mind they have dependencies)